# Magento empty blank product page

Tags: magento, product

I got some problems with my magento store. The product page view is empty.

I've debugged it and in the exception log I got this message:

```
2014-02-18T21:45:34+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Method "addJqueryLibrary" is not defined in "Magentothem_Upsellslider_Model_Layout_Generate_Observer"' in /home/mellimello/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1340): Mage::throwException('Method "addJque...')
#1 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magentothem_Upsellslider_Model_Layout_Generate_Observer), 'addJqueryLibrar...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#3 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(351): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#5 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#6 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(6, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#7 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#8 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#9 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/mellimello/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/mellimello/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the module `Magentothem Upsellslider` is broken. If you installed the module from somewhere else, contact the creator and tell them it isn't working. In the meantime, uninstall it by removing the file `app/code/etc/modules/Magentothem_Upsellslider.xml` and clear your cache.

If this is your module, you seem to be trying to call a non-existent function `addJqueryLibrary` in your observer. Perhaps you have a typo... should it be `addJQueryLibrary`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I deleted the .xml file but without result.

Comment: @user3325536 Clear your cache.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After clearing cache the module was disabled and there was a new error message of another module that i wasn't using. I did the same and enabled the upsellslider again. It's working now. Many thanks

Comment: I am getting the same issue, how can I find what is the issue? There is no console error and log error even view page source also empty.

Comment: @Rathinam here is an article about finding magento error logs: https://amasty.com/blog/magento-error-log-a-starter-guide/

Comment: @DamienBlack Thanks for your knowledge share.